# Excel formulas at column-level

Tags: excel

I'm guessing this is a longshot.
I have a sheet of servers at my workplace, and the applications they run. Servers-to-applications is a many-to-one relationship, i.e.

- A single server runs a single application
- A single application can run on many servers

Column A lists the servers, column B the application run by each server. Therefore, column B has duplicate values.

On a separate sheet, I want to list these applications in column A, without duplicate values, similar to a relational table.

Is there any way to do this using a formula? Then, if a new application is added to the server sheet (say, because a new server is added), a new row is added automatically to the application sheet?

Like I said, I know it's a longshot. I can use VBA but this would be much more convenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any reason why you can't create a Pivot Table in a new worksheet based on Columns A and B?

For the Pivot table Row, you could show Application Name, and for the Values, you could used Count of Server Name to give you a list of Applications that does not contain duplicates.

Every time you want to check for new Applications, refresh the Pivot table.
You can even use COUNTA() to check if there are more rows after you've refreshed.

From there you can reference the list produced by the Pivot Table in any number of ways using formulas that reference the Pivot Table.

Answer (score 2):

With a formula: [Retrieving Unique Values From A List](http://www.exceltip.com/st/Retrieving_Unique_Values_From_A_List/805.html)

> Use the `INDEX`, `MATCH`, and `COUNTIF` functions as shown in the following Array formula:
>
> ```
> {=INDEX($A$2:$A$8,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($B$2:B2,$A$2:$A$8),0))}
> ```
>
> Note:
> The first cell in the unique list (column B) must remain empty.
> The formula should be entered in the second cell and copied down until the #N/A error is returned.

Without a formula: [How do I get the distinct values in a column in Excel?](https://superuser.com/questions/49614/how-do-i-get-the-distinct-values-in-a-column-in-excel)